# Can we use a prefix like a after until?

Tags: grammar

For instance - He lost all meaning in life until a sweet little gesture that gave him some semblance of hope when he needed it the most.

IS this sentence correct

Comment: Unless you can point to *some specific aspect* of the text that you have doubts about (and show evidence that you've unsuccessfully tried to research the matter yourself), this is Off Topic proofreading. Please edit the question accordingly, or it will be closed.

Comment: Hi Kusai, and welcome to the English Language Learners StackExchange. While there are lots of people here who are glad to help out when people are struggling with learning the English language, this isn't a proofreading service. If you could be more specific about what you are unsure of, and why you are unsure of it, we might be able to help.

Comment: At least tell me if you can use a sweet little gesture after until

Answer (score 1):

The cited usage is at best "clumsy". Ignoring the rather florid/poetic context as given by OP, the construction we're dealing with is equivalent to...

> 1: *I had never tasted whisky until a wedding party.*
>    2: *He was poor until a lottery win*
>    3: *We knew nothing until a letter from our daughter*
>   ...

In all these examples, what we logically expect to follow ***until*** should immediately and clearly identify ***some specific point in [past] time***. But what we've *actually* got is simply a ***noun phrase*** - leaving the reader / audience to infer a meaning along the lines of ***the time when I / he / we had*** [the specified np].

---

It's not unusual in English to remove elements that can easily be inferred from context like this, but I think it's worth pointing out that although all the above examples are "credible" (a competent native speaker *might* say them), they'd all be much more likely if we replace ***a*** by ***the***. This would at least imply speaker and audience know ***which*** wedding party / lottery win / letter was being mentioned - in which context it's easier to make the implied leap from *[noun]* to ***time when*** [noun] **happened**.

But this is a fine point of style / pragmatics. There's no *syntactic* reason why ***until*** shouldn't be followed by ***a*** [noun]. It's just that in practice the appropriate circumstances don't arise all that often, so it's a slightly "unfamiliar" construction. Which becomes even more noticeable in OP's rather circumlocutory example, where the reader is already being somewhat taxed by other aspects of the text.

Unfortunately, the "easy fix" for my examples (include ***I / he / we*** before the ***a*** [noun]) isn't so easy in OP's context (there's no really short way of expanding ***a sweet little gesture*** with some verb-based clause to help us convert it to a time-based "event"), so you've either got to live with the awkwardness or go for a much more drastic rewrite of the whole sentence. Personally, I'd choose the second option.

Comment: I agree with you that what is said is grammatical, but a bit odd. But re-writing it to make it a bit more comprehensible  is a snap: omit "that" after "gesture."

Comment: Thank you so much.This kinda detailed explanation can only be provided by a bonafide expert. ..You're amazingKeep up the good work..

Comment: @Jeff Morrow: You're absolutely right! I missed that one! But note that the net effect of removing ***that*** is to give us a meaningful ***verb*** to make a closer link to the relevant action/event  that we need to "locate in time". The clause following ***until*** now more easily translates into *[the time when] a gesture **gave** him [something]*.